# Search Parameters By Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web page that has several search boxes. Customers can search based on First Name, Address, Phone Number. I already have Google analytics script inserted on my web page. I just want to find if it is possible to know which search box has been used by the customer most so which search text box is used more frequently by the customer or the usage of each search box. Can I find this out using Google analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to measure the usage of search boxes in three ways. Firstly, you can push datalayers from your backend with each use of the search boxes. Secondly, you can use an element visibility variable trigger in tag manager if you show a specific text with each search box. Lastly, you can measure clicks on each search box by setting a class or id for the boxes and analyzing it in Analytics, although this method is almost inaccurate.